# ObservableCollection.Clear() throws exception "index out of range"

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, observablecollection

I try to clear an existing ObservableCollection by using a simple `Collection.Clear()`.

It throws:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>   Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

This collection is associated with a ComboxBox in a Flyout I just hide before trying to clear. What else should I do?

Comment: Sounds like you're using the ObservableCollection from multiple threads at the same time, perhaps? ObservableCollection is not thread-safe.

Comment: Please show the code that's throwing the exception

Comment: Might be answered by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61559211/7149454

Answer (score 1):

as canton7 suggested my collection was still being used in the Flyout (hiding the flyout is in fact not enough to close/release). The fix is simply to assign/deassign collection to ComboBox.